# How to pass data from child to parent's sibling? (Unable to do it via context)

Tags: reactjs

I'm facing an issue regarding passing data around and the structure of my application.

My  `Search` component:

```js
const SearchBar = (props) => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    search: "",
    results: [],
    searched: false,
  });
  const handleInputChange = (evt) => {
    //handle input change
  };

  const search = async () => {
    //fetch the search results from backend and update the state with search results
    list()
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input
        className="search"
        value={values.search}
        onChange={handleInputChange}
      />
      {/* <PostList cover={false} items={values.results} /> */}
    </>
  );
};
```

It is inside a `Nav` component.

This is what my `Posts` component (a sibling to `Nav`) looks like:

```js
const Posts = () => {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const auth = useContext(AuthContext);
  const postsContext = useContext(PostContext);

  return (
    <div className="posts-wrapper">
      //render list of all posts
      <PostList
        items={postsContext.loadedPosts}
        searched={false}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Initially, `Posts` should render a list of all posts. But when a user uses the search, it should render only the matching results. How should I go about doing that?

I can obviously have the `Search` component render the list of matching results (see the commented line in `Search`) but that won't work because then I'll have 2 `PostList` components (one for matching results and one for all posts)

I tried using context but didn't work! (Because the context for the `Posts` component won't change)

Here's the context setup:

```js
const PostContext = createContext({
  loadedPosts: [],
  onLike: () => {},
  onSave: () => {},
});

const PostsProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [loadedPosts, setLoadedPosts] = useState([]);
  const auth = useContext(AuthContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPosts = async () => {
      try {
        const responseData = await sendReq(`http://localhost:5000/api/posts`);
        setLoadedPosts(responseData.posts);
        //postContext = {...postContext, loadedPosts}
      } catch (err) {}
    };
    fetchPosts();
  }, [sendReq]);

  return (
    <PostContext.Provider
      value={{ loadedPosts, onLike: likeHandler, onSave: saveHandler }}
    >
      {children}
    </PostContext.Provider>
  );
};

const App = () => {
   //relevant code
   return (
    <PostsProvider>
      <AuthContext.Provider
        value={{
          isLoggedIn: !!token,
          userId,
          login,
          logout,
          currentUser: user,
        }}
      >
        <Router>
          <Nav />
          <Switch>{routes}</Switch>
        </Router>
      </AuthContext.Provider>
    </PostsProvider>
  );
```

In `Search`:

```js
const SearchBar = (props) => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    search: "",
    results: [],
    searched: false,
  });
  const handleInputChange = (evt) => {
    //handle input change
  };

  const search = async () => {
    //fetch the search results from backend and update the state with search results
    //update context
    postContext = {...postContext, loadedPosts: values.results};
    console.log(postContext.loadedPosts); //works! but this won't 
    //update context value for `Posts` and re-render it
    //is it because `Posts` is not being re-rendered (bc not state 
    //change and hence can't consume the updated context value?
    list()
  };
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use a filter() function to display the matched posts. To do so, follow this video on (39:16 minute:second): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eHnqS9kMH-s&list=PL0Zuz27SZ-6PrE9srvEn8nbhOOyxnWXfp&index=17

Comment: @Abdulhakim Hey, that was actually my initial solution but I switched to rendering only a limited number (say, 10) of posts on the first render and then implement infinite rendering and search the backend for all posts

Answer (score 0):

Passing data horizontally across application is one of the main reasons that state management tools exist for react, prior to context it was always a pain to get bits of state shared between "sibling" components.

And if you aren't having any luck with the native react context I would suggest looking into using a state manager. The most popular is redux (not the simplest to learn though) but for something quick and easy i'd recommend something like mobx, this will allow you to update the search results in your Search component and render that change in your Posts component.

[An introduction to Mobx](https://mobx.js.org/getting-started)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! Yes, I was considering a state management library but I wanted to use "pure" react in my first project. Regarding the problem I'm facing with context, after search, context is updated via `postContext = {...postContext, loadedPosts: searchResults}`. And `console.log(postContext.loadedPosts)` consists of matching posts. But when I check the component tree in inspector, `Context.Provider` still says the original array of posts (?). Also, not sure how to re-render the `Posts` component on context update.

Please correct me if the approach feels wrong!

Comment: I guess without seeing how you have set the context up I wouldn't be able to say if anything "stands out" so-to-speak.

Comment: Hey, just updated the post to add my context setup!

Comment: Where are you rendering `<PostsProvider />` I can see it creating a provider around any of its children but i'm not seeing it being rendered anywhere. I'm not convincved you even need that `PostsProvider` component in all honest. Would it not make more sense to fetch the posts in the posts component and then update the context from there rather than having this over-arching component you need to wrap everything in?

Comment: Hey, sorry I just thought that wasn't relevant but I've updated the post to include it. The reason I made a `PostsProvider` component was because there were some `PostList` instances that needed to consume context changes but were not able to do (because of the structure). bUt I'll rethink it and try your approach! Will let you know if it works! Thanks!

Comment: Hey, I made a parent component for both `Search` and `Posts` and used component composition to achieve the desired result! Your approach also helped a lot! Thanks! :)